# Laravel Mix React Component Not Rendering After Setting Alias to Apache2

Tags: reactjs, laravel, apache2, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I tried hard for two days almost and still failed to render React components using Laravel Mix when I set my domain alias in Apache2 configuration.

```
domain name : http://dev.propertydodo.ae
Alias /admin-panel /var/www/html/pdd-admin/public
complete path is http://dev.propertydodo.ae/admin-panel
To fetch api its working path is http://dev.propertydodo.ae/admin-panel/api/v1
```

Below is my Laravel Mix configuration.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------        ------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loaders: [
          'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0',
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
}).react('resources/assets/js/locations.js', 'public/js')
  .react('resources/assets/js/dashboard.js', 'public/js')
  .react('resources/assets/js/payment.js', 'public/js')
  .sourceMaps()
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

---

Below is index.blade.php where I render location.js which is Babel compiled React asset files to a single JS file.

```
<div id='locations' class="content-wrapper">
</div>
<script src="{{route('baseurl') .  mix('js/locations.js') }}"> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough to link ur js file

```
<script src="{{mix('js/locations.js')}}">
```